# How to condense a large battery of conditions into a lookup array?

Tags: php, function, refactoring, lookup-tables

I am trying to write a function that looks up an `$InterestRate` value for insurance payments on a car. I have inserted the table below the code:

Currently I have tried:

```
function interestRate() {
if ((int)$VehicleYear >= 2001) && (int)$VehicleYear <= 2005){

    $Term = 24;

    if ((int)$CreditScore >= 720){
        $InterestRate = 15.90;
    }
    elseif ((int)$CreditScore >= 610) || ((int)$CreditScore <= 719) {
        $InterestRate = 19.90;
    }
    elseif ((int)$CreditScore >= 580) || ((int)$CreditScore <= 609) {
        $InterestRate = 22.90;
    }
    elseif ((int)$CreditScore >= 530) || ((int)$CreditScore <= 579) {
        $InterestRate = 22.90;
    }
    elseif ((int)$CreditScore >= 489) || ((int)$CreditScore <= 529) {
        $InterestRate = 22.90;
    }
}

if ((int)$VehicleYear == 2006){

    $Term = 24;

    if ((int)$CreditScore >= 720){
        $InterestRate = 15.90;
    }
    elseif ((int)$CreditScore >= 610) || ((int)$CreditScore <= 719) {
        $InterestRate = 18.90;
    }
    elseif ((int)$CreditScore >= 580) || ((int)$CreditScore <= 609) {
        $InterestRate = 21.90;
    }
    elseif ((int)$CreditScore >= 530) || ((int)$CreditScore <= 579) {
        $InterestRate = 22.90;
    }
    elseif ((int)$CreditScore >= 489) || ((int)$CreditScore <= 529) {
        $InterestRate = 22.90;
    }
}
if ((int)$VehicleYear == 2007){

    $Term = 36;

    if ((int)$CreditScore >= 720){
        $InterestRate = 15.90;
    }
    elseif ((int)$CreditScore >= 610) || ((int)$CreditScore <= 719) {
        $InterestRate = 18.90;
    }
    elseif ((int)$CreditScore >= 580) || ((int)$CreditScore <= 609) {
        $InterestRate = 21.90;
    }
    elseif ((int)$CreditScore >= 530) || ((int)$CreditScore <= 579) {
        $InterestRate = 22.90;
    }
    elseif ((int)$CreditScore >= 489) || ((int)$CreditScore <= 529) {
        $InterestRate = 22.90;
    }
}
if ((int)$VehicleYear == 2008){

    $Term = 36;

    if ((int)$CreditScore >= 720){
        $InterestRate = 14.90;
    }
    elseif ((int)$CreditScore >= 610) || ((int)$CreditScore <= 719) {
        $InterestRate = 17.90;
    }
    elseif ((int)$CreditScore >= 580) || ((int)$CreditScore <= 609) {
        $InterestRate = 21.90;
    }
    elseif ((int)$CreditScore >= 530) || ((int)$CreditScore <= 579) {
        $InterestRate = 21.90;
    }
    elseif ((int)$CreditScore >= 489) || ((int)$CreditScore <= 529) {
        $InterestRate = 21.90;
    }
}

if ((int)$VehicleYear == 2009){

    $Term = 36;

    if ((int)$CreditScore >= 720){
        $InterestRate = 14.90;
    }
    elseif ((int)$CreditScore >= 610) || ((int)$CreditScore <= 719) {
        $InterestRate = 17.90;
    }
    elseif ((int)$CreditScore >= 580) || ((int)$CreditScore <= 609) {
        $InterestRate = 20.90;
    }
    elseif ((int)$CreditScore >= 530) || ((int)$CreditScore <= 579) {
        $InterestRate = 20.90;
    }
    elseif ((int)$CreditScore >= 489) || ((int)$CreditScore <= 529) {
        $InterestRate = 20.90;
    }
}

if ((int)$VehicleYear == 2010){

    $Term = 36;

    if ((int)$CreditScore >= 720){
        $InterestRate = 14.90;
    }
    elseif ((int)$CreditScore >= 610) || ((int)$CreditScore <= 719) {
        $InterestRate = 17.90;
    }
    elseif ((int)$CreditScore >= 580) || ((int)$CreditScore <= 609) {
        $InterestRate = 20.90;
    }
    elseif ((int)$CreditScore >= 530) || ((int)$CreditScore <= 579) {
        $InterestRate = 20.90;
    }
    elseif ((int)$CreditScore >= 489) || ((int)$CreditScore <= 529) {
        $InterestRate = 20.90;
    }
}

if ((int)$VehicleYear == 2011){

    $Term = 42;

    if ((int)$CreditScore >= 720){
        $InterestRate = 14.90;
    }
    elseif ((int)$CreditScore >= 610) || ((int)$CreditScore <= 719) {
        $InterestRate = 16.90;
    }
    elseif ((int)$CreditScore >= 580) || ((int)$CreditScore <= 609) {
        $InterestRate = 19.90;
    }
    elseif ((int)$CreditScore >= 530) || ((int)$CreditScore <= 579) {
        $InterestRate = 19.90;
    }
    elseif ((int)$CreditScore >= 489) || ((int)$CreditScore <= 529) {
        $InterestRate = 20.90;
    }
}

if ((int)$VehicleYear == 2012){

    $Term = 42;

    if ((int)$CreditScore >= 720){
        $InterestRate = 12.90;
    }
    elseif ((int)$CreditScore >= 610) || ((int)$CreditScore <= 719) {
        $InterestRate = 15.90;
    }
    elseif ((int)$CreditScore >= 580) || ((int)$CreditScore <= 609) {
        $InterestRate = 18.90;
    }
    elseif ((int)$CreditScore >= 530) || ((int)$CreditScore <= 579) {
        $InterestRate = 19.90;
    }
    elseif ((int)$CreditScore >= 489) || ((int)$CreditScore <= 529) {
        $InterestRate = 19.90;
    }
}

if ((int)$VehicleYear == 2013){

    $Term = 42;

    if ((int)$CreditScore >= 720){
        $InterestRate = 12.90;
    }
    elseif ((int)$CreditScore >= 610) || ((int)$CreditScore <= 719) {
        $InterestRate = 15.90;
    }
    elseif ((int)$CreditScore >= 580) || ((int)$CreditScore <= 609) {
        $InterestRate = 18.90;
    }
    elseif ((int)$CreditScore >= 530) || ((int)$CreditScore <= 579) {
        $InterestRate = 18.90;
    }
    elseif ((int)$CreditScore >= 489) || ((int)$CreditScore <= 529) {
        $InterestRate = 18.90;
    }
}

if ((int)$VehicleYear >= 2014){

    $Term = 48;

    if ((int)$CreditScore >= 720){
        $InterestRate = 11.90;
    }
    elseif ((int)$CreditScore >= 610) || ((int)$CreditScore <= 719) {
        $InterestRate = 14.90;
    }
    elseif ((int)$CreditScore >= 580) || ((int)$CreditScore <= 609) {
        $InterestRate = 17.90;
    }
    elseif ((int)$CreditScore >= 530) || ((int)$CreditScore <= 579) {
        $InterestRate = 18.90;
    }
    elseif ((int)$CreditScore >= 489) || ((int)$CreditScore <= 529) {
        $InterestRate = 18.90;
    }
}
}
```

It is both tedious and simply does not work when I try to use `$InterestRate` in a calculation. What is the best way to approach this one?

**EDIT** : Some have mentioned using an SQL table. I have no idea how to do that. But here is my table basically

```html
<table style="undefined;table-layout: fixed; width: 497px">
<colgroup>
<col style="width: 93px">
<col style="width: 73px">
<col style="width: 75px">
<col style="width: 64px">
<col style="width: 64px">
<col style="width: 64px">
<col style="width: 64px">
</colgroup>
  <tr>
    <th>Vehicle Year</th>
    <th>Term</th>
    <th>FICO</th>
    <th>FICO</th>
    <th>FICO</th>
    <th>FICO</th>
    <th>FICO</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>720 +</td>
    <td>719-610</td>
    <td>609-580</td>
    <td>579-530</td>
    <td>529-489</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2014-current</td>
    <td>48</td>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>14</td>
    <td>17</td>
    <td>18</td>
    <td>18</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2013</td>
    <td>42</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>15</td>
    <td>18</td>
    <td>18</td>
    <td>18</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2012</td>
    <td>42</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>15</td>
    <td>18</td>
    <td>19</td>
    <td>19</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2011</td>
    <td>42</td>
    <td>14</td>
    <td>16</td>
    <td>19</td>
    <td>19</td>
    <td>20</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2010</td>
    <td>36</td>
    <td>14</td>
    <td>17</td>
    <td>20</td>
    <td>20</td>
    <td>20</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2009</td>
    <td>36</td>
    <td>14</td>
    <td>17</td>
    <td>20</td>
    <td>20</td>
    <td>20</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2008</td>
    <td>36</td>
    <td>14</td>
    <td>17</td>
    <td>21</td>
    <td>21</td>
    <td>21</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2007</td>
    <td>36</td>
    <td>15</td>
    <td>18</td>
    <td>21</td>
    <td>22</td>
    <td>21</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2006</td>
    <td>24</td>
    <td>15</td>
    <td>18</td>
    <td>21</td>
    <td>22</td>
    <td>22</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2001-2005</td>
    <td>24</td>
    <td>15</td>
    <td>19</td>
    <td>22</td>
    <td>22</td>
    <td>22</td>
  </tr>
</table>
Extra o
```

Comment: Neither you're passing `$ssn` and `$VehicleYear` values to the function nor you're using `global`. How did you get this `$ssn` and `$VehicleYear` values inside the function?

Comment: oh sorry, let me fix that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go: all duplicate code is removed:

```
function creditScore( $cs ) {
    $cs = (int) $cs;

    if     ($cs >= 720)               return 5;
    elseif ($cs >= 610 && $cs <= 719) return 4;
    elseif ($cs >= 580 && $cs <= 609) return 3;
    elseif ($cs >= 530 && $cs <= 579) return 2;
    elseif ($cs >= 489 && $cs <= 529) return 1;
    else                              return 0;
}

function interestRate($vehicleYear, $creditScore) {
    $vehicleYear = (int) $vehicleYear;
    $cred = creditScore( $creditScore );
    if ( ! $cred )      // handle credit score below 489: returns 0
        throw new Exception("Unsupported creditScore: $creditScore" );
    $cred--;    // otherwise it's 1..5, change to 0..4 for array index

    $rates = [
        2001 => [ 'term' => 24, 'rates' => [ 22.90, 22.90, 22.90, 19.90, 15.90 ] ],
        2002 => [ 'term' => 24, 'rates' => [ 22.90, 22.90, 22.90, 19.90, 15.90 ] ],
        2003 => [ 'term' => 24, 'rates' => [ 22.90, 22.90, 22.90, 19.90, 15.90 ] ],
        2004 => [ 'term' => 24, 'rates' => [ 22.90, 22.90, 22.90, 19.90, 15.90 ] ],
        2005 => [ 'term' => 24, 'rates' => [ 22.90, 22.90, 22.90, 19.90, 15.90 ] ],
        2006 => [ 'term' => 24, 'rates' => [ 22.90, 22.90, 21.90, 18.90, 15.90 ] ],
        2007 => [ 'term' => 36, 'rates' => [ 22.90, 22.90, 21.90, 18.90, 15.90 ] ],
        2008 => [ 'term' => 36, 'rates' => [ 22.90, 22.90, 21.90, 17.90, 14.90 ] ],
        2009 => [ 'term' => 36, 'rates' => [ 20.90, 20.90, 20.90, 17.90, 14.90 ] ],
        2010 => [ 'term' => 36, 'rates' => [ 20.90, 20.90, 20.90, 17.90, 14.90 ] ],
        2011 => [ 'term' => 42, 'rates' => [ 20.90, 19.90, 19.90, 16.90, 14.90 ] ],
        2012 => [ 'term' => 42, 'rates' => [ 19.90, 19.90, 18.90, 15.90, 12.90 ] ],
        2013 => [ 'term' => 42, 'rates' => [ 18.90, 18.90, 18.90, 15.90, 12.90 ] ],
        2014 => [ 'term' => 48, 'rates' => [ 18.90, 18.90, 17.90, 14.90, 11.90 ] ],
    ];

    return [ // TODO: check if isset( $rates[$vehicleYear ])
        $rates[$vehicleYear]['rates'][ $cred ],
        $rates[$vehicleYear]['term']
    ];
}

list( $interestRate, $term ) = interestRate( 2013, 666 );
```

Comment: I am not sure how this actually works and how i would use it. I am updating the question with proper variables by the way.

Comment: Ok i'll explain that and also how to do it without SQL in a lookup table. GImme a few secs.

Comment: I created a table and put it in the question details to see what  I am dealing with

Comment: Updated the answer - I removed the SQL since you're not familiar with it.

Comment: This works perfect. I have taken my time to fully understand what you are doing at each stage. Thanks so much.

Comment: You're welcome - I figured the code was pretty self-explanatory, but if you need me to clarify anything feel free to ask!

Answer (score 0):

I like some, but not all of Kenney's answer.  I lookup array for rates is a good idea, but it should only be declared once instead of every time a function is called.  The short battery of `if`s to determine the credit score index is good, but the second condition (`<=`) of each branch is logically unnecessary.

I recommend defining lookup array as a constant so that it is declared just once and has global scope.  This is completely appropriate because the amounts in the lookup table should never change during processing.

When a lookup array is properly designed, maintenance/extension should only involve adjusting the lookup array and never the processing code.

This sets up your php code to be one-step away from being transferred to a database table -- in the event that your application finds an increased demand for data maintenance or extension.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/0oDqG))

```
define(
    'TERM_RATES_BY_YEAR',
    [
        2001 => ['term' => 24, 'rates' => [15.90, 19.90, 22.90, 22.90, 22.90]],
        2002 => ['term' => 24, 'rates' => [15.90, 19.90, 22.90, 22.90, 22.90]],
        2003 => ['term' => 24, 'rates' => [15.90, 19.90, 22.90, 22.90, 22.90]],
        2004 => ['term' => 24, 'rates' => [15.90, 19.90, 22.90, 22.90, 22.90]],
        2005 => ['term' => 24, 'rates' => [15.90, 19.90, 22.90, 22.90, 22.90]],
        2006 => ['term' => 24, 'rates' => [15.90, 18.90, 21.90, 22.90, 22.90]],
        2007 => ['term' => 36, 'rates' => [15.90, 18.90, 21.90, 22.90, 22.90]],
        2008 => ['term' => 36, 'rates' => [14.90, 17.90, 21.90, 22.90, 22.90]],
        2009 => ['term' => 36, 'rates' => [14.90, 17.90, 20.90, 20.90, 20.90]],
        2010 => ['term' => 36, 'rates' => [14.90, 17.90, 20.90, 20.90, 20.90]],
        2011 => ['term' => 42, 'rates' => [14.90, 16.90, 19.90, 19.90, 20.90]],
        2012 => ['term' => 42, 'rates' => [12.90, 15.90, 18.90, 19.90, 19.90]],
        2013 => ['term' => 42, 'rates' => [12.90, 15.90, 18.90, 18.90, 18.90]],
        2014 => ['term' => 48, 'rates' => [11.90, 14.90, 17.90, 18.90, 18.90]],
    ]
);
define('CREDIT_SCORE_MINIMUM_THRESHOLDS', [720, 610, 580, 530, 489]);

/** @throws Exception */
function getRateIndexFromCreditScore(int $creditScore): ?int
{
    foreach (CREDIT_SCORE_MINIMUM_THRESHOLDS as $rateIndex => $minThreshold) {
        if ($creditScore >= $minThreshold) {
            return $rateIndex;
        }
    }
    throw new Exception("Sorry, your credit score ($creditScore) does not qualify for financing");
}

foreach (range(2000, 2015) as $year) {
    try {
        if (!isset(TERM_RATES_BY_YEAR[$year])) {
            throw new Exception("Sorry, your vehicle year ($year) does not qualify for financing");
        }
        $score = rand(300, 850);
        $rateIndex = getRateIndexFromCreditScore($score);
        $outcome = sprintf(
            'Vehicle Year: %d, Credit Score: %d, Term: %d, Rate: %.2f',
            $year,
            $score,
            TERM_RATES_BY_YEAR[$year]['term'],
            TERM_RATES_BY_YEAR[$year]['rates'][$rateIndex]
        );
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $outcome = $e->getMessage();
    }
    echo "$outcome\n";
}
```

Potential Output:

```
Sorry, your vehicle year (2000) does not qualify for financing
Vehicle Year: 2001, Credit Score: 758, Term: 24, Rate: 15.90
Sorry, your credit score (401) does not qualify for financing
Vehicle Year: 2003, Credit Score: 751, Term: 24, Rate: 15.90
Vehicle Year: 2004, Credit Score: 545, Term: 24, Rate: 22.90
Sorry, your credit score (481) does not qualify for financing
Vehicle Year: 2006, Credit Score: 658, Term: 24, Rate: 18.90
Vehicle Year: 2007, Credit Score: 745, Term: 36, Rate: 15.90
Vehicle Year: 2008, Credit Score: 836, Term: 36, Rate: 14.90
Vehicle Year: 2009, Credit Score: 803, Term: 36, Rate: 14.90
Sorry, your credit score (466) does not qualify for financing
Vehicle Year: 2011, Credit Score: 792, Term: 42, Rate: 14.90
Vehicle Year: 2012, Credit Score: 763, Term: 42, Rate: 12.90
Vehicle Year: 2013, Credit Score: 534, Term: 42, Rate: 18.90
Vehicle Year: 2014, Credit Score: 493, Term: 48, Rate: 18.90
Sorry, your vehicle year (2015) does not qualify for financing
```